# How to give Timeout in ActivityTrigger - Azure Durable Function

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

```
[FunctionName("A_SimulateLongRunningTask")]
public static async Task<object> TaskExecutor([ActivityTrigger] string taskInput, TraceWriter log)
{
     var timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30); 
  var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout);
  var cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;
   //var oldSessionsTask = doing some stuff here
   await Task.WhenAny(Task.WhenAll(oldSessionsTask), cancellationToken);
   return null;
}
```

** i want to keep timeout at ActivityTrigger level in Azure Durable Function,but it showing error.
ERROR- can not convert System.Threading.CancellationToken to System.Threading.Tasks.Task ***

Comment: You're passing a cancellation token to Task.WhenAll which only accepts tasks. The tasks passed in should have cancellation set up. This needs to be done in the `oldSessionsTask` you're not showing us. If that cannot be done, you can also create task that cancels using Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, cancellationToken). However, all of this has very little to do with durable functions, this is just async/await in vanilla C#, since this is activity code. You could reproduce this with a console app.

Answer (score 1):

> How to give Timeout in ActivityTrigger - Azure Durable Function

I have reproduced in my environment and below are my expected results:

**`The code which worked for me:`**

```
   [Function(nameof(SayHelloAsync))]
   public static async Task<string> SayHelloAsync([ActivityTrigger] string name, FunctionContext executionContext)
   {
       var timeout1 = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
       var cancellationTokenSource1 = new CancellationTokenSource();
       var timeouttask1 = Task.Delay(timeout1, cancellationTokenSource1.Token);
       var task = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)); 
       var donetask = await Task.WhenAny(task, timeouttask1);

       if (donetask == timeouttask1)
       {
           ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger("SayHello");
           logger.LogInformation("Task timed out Rithwik.");
           return null; //
       }

       return null;
   }
```

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]